# Not able to connect to cluster. Facing Certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: kubernetes

I am not sure either what I am trying to do is possible or correct way.

One of my colleague spinup kubernetes gce cluster (with 1 master and 4 minions.) in a project which is shared with me as owner access.

After setup he shared his ~/.kubernetes_auth keys along with .kubecfg.crt, .kubecfg.ca.crt and .kubecfg.key. I copied all of the at my home folder and setup the kubernetes workspace.
I also set the project name as a default project in geconfig. and now I can connect to the master and slaves using `'gcutil ssh --zone us-central1-b kubernetes-master'`

But when I try to list of existing pods using `'cluster/kubecfg.sh list pods'`
I see

```
"F1017 21:05:31.037148 18021 kubecfg.go:422] Got request error: Get https://107.178.208.109/api/v1beta1/pods?namespace=default: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "ChangeMe")
```

I tried to debug from my side but failed to come any conclusion. Any sort of clue will be helpful.

Comment: I am seeing a slightly different error message: F1019 15:57:22.698105 12315 kubecfg.go:403] Got request error: Post https://146.148.65.49/api/v1beta1/pods: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also copy the cert files off of the master again.  They are located in /usr/share/nginx on the master.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably due to a not implemented feature, see this issue:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/issues/1886

you can copy the files from /usr/share/nginx/... on the master
into your home dir and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround: set the -insecure_skip_tls_verify option

In kubecfg.sh, change the code near the bottom to

```
else
  auth_config=(
    "-insecure_skip_tls_verify"
  )
fi
```

Obviously this is insecure and you are putting yourself at risk of a man in the middle attack, etc.